# Lost tethering access and slow internet after uninstalling root firewall

Tags: root-access, internet, tethering, firewall

Since I uninstalled root firewall, I've been facing a lot of bugs concerning network connectivity; I lost tethering access and the internet became so slow. Even browsers have reported "connection refused" issues.

How to fix this?

Comment: Which specific firewall are we talking about?

Comment: I dont know what you mean but i was using "Android firewall". It's available on play store.

Answer (score 1):

With the help of a root browser, navigate to `/system/bin/` and clear the content of the following files: `iptables`, `ip6tables` (using the text editor that comes with root browser) then set permissions for each file to read & execute only.
(Remark: This will also restore tethering access)